# What's the proper collection for indexing with several objects?

Tags: java, collections

Suppose I have this array:

```
double[][] Q = new double[n1][n2];
```

I could index the values of `Q` by using `int` indexes, such as `Q[2][1]`. But in my case, `n1` is a `byte[]`, not an `int`. I still know the possible values of `n1` (e.g, all possible combinations of the array values). What collection should I use instead of an `array`?

```
HashMap<byte[], Double>[] Q = new HashMap[n2];
```

This was my solution, but I'm not sure it is adequate. To index, I can do

```
byte[] n1 = {1,0,6,1,4,2,5,1};
Q[1].get(n1);
```

Is there a better way to do this? Something that is more performant? I think having an array of HashMaps is not ideal, but can I add that `int` to my key? How?

---

As stated in the comments,

> The problem with using an array as a hashmap key (aside from the fact that it's mutable) is that arrays don't calculate their hashcode based on their contents; so you couldn't actually look up a value in the map unless you have the actual key instance.

So how do I use an array as an indexing key? A stupid solution would be to always convert it to String before using it, but I'm sure there are better and proper solutions.

Comment: An `int` is wider than a `byte`, so what is the problem with using a 2D array?  Granted, your problem might do better with another data structure.

Comment: The problem with using an array as a hashmap key (aside from the fact that it's mutable) is that arrays don't calculate their hashcode based on their contents; so you couldn't actually look up a value in the map unless you have the actual key instance.

Comment: ah! So how can I used the array to index? Do I have to convert it to `String` every single time? What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: You could wrap it in another class that overrides `equals` and `hashCode` using the array's content and use that as a key.

Comment: For what are those byte arrays used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to go for your problem is to define a complex key class, which basically consists of your byte[] and int, write reliable hashCode and equals-Methods for this class, and use it as a key to the HashMap.

This way, you can use the runtime and memory efficiency of a hashmap and encapsulate the complexity of the key in a separate class.

Code to illustrate:

```
public static class MyKey {
    private int    i;
    private byte[] b;

    private MyKey(int i, byte[] b) {
        this.i = i;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static MyKey of(int i, byte ... b) {
        return new MyKey(i, b);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {  // Autogenerated from eclipse
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(b);
        result = prime * result + i;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {  // Autogenerated from eclipse
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        if(obj == null)
            return false;
        if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MyKey other = (MyKey) obj;
        if(!Arrays.equals(b, other.b))
            return false;
        if(i != other.i)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<MyKey, Double> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
    valueMap.put(MyKey.of(1, (byte)2, (byte)4, (byte)7), 0.1);
    valueMap.put(MyKey.of(1, new byte[] { 3, 8, 14 }), 0.1);
}
```

Comment: what is purpose of using i variable?

Comment: Note that you should take a defensive copy of `b` in the constructor, in order that the array held by the class cannot be tampered with after creation. Also, the class should be `final`, as should the member variables, in order to make it truly immutable.

Comment: The i variable represents the int-index in the OP's question. Thus, such a complex key class can replace the complete indexing.